# If SM Bus Controller is missing is that of any consequence

Tags: windows, drivers

I recently upgraded an Optiplex 3020 to Windows 10.  All drivers work on it except for the 'SM Bus Controller'.  I've tried various drivers/installers to get it working but they all failed for one reason or another.  One said "platform not supported" leading me to believe that it's just too old.

But is it of any consequence if I just leave that driver not installed?

So far everything seems to be working fine on it.

Comment: Install the appropriate chipset driver from this page, choose you OS first>>>>https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/optiplex-3020m-desktop/drivers

Comment: May uninstall device and restart Windows 10, windows 10 Device Manager will reinstall the uninstalled SM Bus Controller driver.